# Reproduce the API links appearing in Google search results

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, web-crawlers, robots.txt, noindex

We have the following problem. The links to our API (that doesn't require any authentication) have suddenly started showing up in Google and Bing search results. As far as we know, these links have not been posted under our domain and must have been posted somewhere else (presumably) or got indexed the way that is described in [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122456/is-possible-to-prevent-third-party-links-to-web-page-from-appearing-in-google-se).

In order to remediate the issue we added an `x-robots-tag` HTTP header with value of "`noindex, nofollow, noarchive`" to our API responses. We also added the path that API resides at to our `robots.txt`, `Disallow` directive (which I believe to be redundant, as it can interfere with `x-robots-tag` and is not respected when the indexing is happening from a third-party page, based on my research).

The issue seems to have been fixed since we no longer can see those links in Google search results, yet we're still feeling uneasy based on the info we learned while researching the topic. One specific case that is bothering us is that we presumably can not prevent search engines from indexing links to our API if they are posted on third-party web pages. Since those pages are eventually indexed, and even though the API links would respond with the aforementioned header, the body of the page they are posted on is still indexed and thus shown in the search results.

In order to test this we posted a couple of links to that API (one with `x-robots-tag` HTTP header fix, another - without) to figure out if this header is indeed blocking link indexing, yet got quite a perplexing result so far. Neither of those links got indexed by Google even though the page they are posted on got indexed and is showing in search results. The question here is the following: how did those links get indexed in the first place and how can we get the new links indexed as well so we can actually test our solution?